# Add sliding effect in display block and display none div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slidetoggle

I'm using a JS function to show/hide a DIV on smaller screens but the function I'm using is just opening the DIV and not sliding it.

here is the JS code.

```
$('.searchBtn').click(function (){
     var nav = $('.SearchParameters');
     if(nav.hasClass('showing')){
         nav.removeClass('showing').addClass('hiding');
     }else{
         nav.removeClass('hiding').addClass('showing');
     }
 });
$(window).resize(function(){
    var winwidth = $(window).innerWidth();
    if(winwidth > 768){
        $('.SearchParameters').removeClass('showing').removeClass('hiding');
    }
});
```

Here is the CSS

```
.SearchParameters.showing {
    display: block;
}
.SearchParameters.hiding {
    display: none;
}
```

I don't want to add height because there is border on the DIV and it appears like a thin line. This DIV is only shown when the site is opened in mobile device screen.

Answer (score 0):

Simply because you never animate it. If you want to have slide effects you could use for an example

```
if (menuClicked === false) {
        $('.slide-menu').animate(
        {
            margin: '0 0 0 0'
        }, 200);
        menuClicked = true;
    }
    else
    {
        $('.slide-menu').animate(
        {
            margin: '0 0 0 -180px'
        }, 200);
        menuClicked = false;
    }
```

css for default view:

```
.slide-menu 
{
position: fixed;
height: 100%;
width: 180px;
margin: 0 0 0 -180px;
}
```

One idea could be to move your content out of the visible are of the screen aslong it is "hidden" and if you "show" it you just change the position of your content to something in the visible area.